# Prevent gaction from closing the conversation when no intent match

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

I am using GAction and dialogflow for building a converstion bot.
**Issue** - For 3 consecutive times if there is no intent match in dialogflow GAction is leaving the conversation.
I want to override this and continue the conersation. How to achieve this?

Comment: You can improve on your UX instead. Guide [here](https://medium.com/google-developers/handling-actions-no-match-errors-in-dialogflow-three-strikes-and-you-re-out-25cfd7f58c7f)

Answer (score 0):

You can manage this using webhook. Enable fulfillment for the Default Fallback Intent and handle its response from the webhook. We are using the same thing in our action, you can also give it a try.